# OraOLEDB.Oracle provider is not registered on the local machine - VS2017

Tags: database, visual-studio-2017, oracle12c

On a Win10 PC I'm trying to connect to a Oracle Database via a VS 2017 project.
Once a call to the database is done, I keep getting this error. 
I already tried to install the Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) 12c and registered the dll file (OraOLEDB12.dll) and add the TNS to the system variables, but without any success.
Does anyone has a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deinstalling everything from Oracle Clients from my PC and just installing the 32-bit Provider Client and registering the OraOLEDB12.dll.

Answer (score 0):

I changed IIS Apppool to 32 bit and it worked